# doubts at Active Directory using C#

Tags: c#, active-directory

I've got a web application that is using Active Directory. 
I create a function to perform  authentication domain, in parameter ( User,Password, and own domain ).
In determinat line  displays a messagem "Unspecified error", as the function below:

```
public bool IsAuthenticated(string domain, string username, string pwd)
    {

        string domainAndUsername = domain + @"\" + username;
        DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(_path, domainAndUsername, pwd);

        try
        {
            //Bind to the native AdsObject to force authentication.
           ---> This Line occurred error
             **object obj = entry.NativeObject;** 
           ---> Line Above occurred error

            DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(entry);

            search.Filter = "(SAMAccountName=" + username + ")";
            search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");
            SearchResult result = search.FindOne();

            if (null == result)
            {
                return false;
            }

            //Update the new path to the user in the directory.
            _path = result.Path;
            _filterAttribute = (string)result.Properties["cn"][0];
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error authenticating user. " + ex.Message);
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Error not Specified
   in System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail)

Comment: *Never* do `throw new Exception("Error authenticating user. " + ex.Message)`.  **Always** do `throw new Exception("Error authenticating user.", ex)`.  That way you never lose stack trace information on your wrapped exception.

Comment: This seems a long winded way of doing it and kind of unnecessary.

are you just trying to Authenticate a user against an AD domain using username and password? If you are you simply need a "PrincipleContext" object

Comment: So what is the exception type?

Comment: I need to perform authentication in a client server, I'm currently trying to authenticate on my own machine using the IP 127.0.0.1

Comment: You need to provide some more information. Removing the authentication part the code runs fine for me but I'm already authenticated and my guess is that you are accessing an AD from a non-AD account?

Comment: Searching on Google, I do not know if I need to change any settings in Administrative Tools in Windows Seven?

Comment: Yes, I need authentication by AD.
This function created within a class.cs

Comment: This code, also won't "authenticate" if the user is not authorized to read AD information.  If they're not it will throw an exception.

Comment: Obtaining Additional information about this, a site link that went un need to download this file "Remote Server Administration Tools for Windows 7", the website, after my application to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

```
using(PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "YOURDOMAIN"))
{
    // validate the credentials
    bool isValid = pc.ValidateCredentials("myuser", "mypassword")
}
```

This is probably going to work better for your needs.  You need .NET3.5 at least and is what you should be using to authenticate.